# Retry for 5XX error occurrence on REST Call - POST Method

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to do one REST API call for POST method.

There will be around 500 plus calls to the same endpoint from different hosts.

It is resulting in 503 error, Hence I tried to achieve the retry mechanism using Retry function of requests module.

Even though after implementing the retry function still am getting same error.

Code snippet is as below:

```
import requests

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
import json

s = requests.Session()
retries = Retry(total=3, backoff_factor=0.3, status_forcelist=[502, 503, 504],
                method_whitelist=frozenset(['GET', 'POST']))
s.mount('https//', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
s.mount('http//', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
response = s.post(url, json=json_payload, headers=headers)
```

Still am getting an error with 503.

Already gone through previous answers for same pattern of question, But i don't find more information regarding this.

Note: Here script is executed at same time from 525 hosts  so around 500 plus hosts will try to trigger the call to the url(internal url), so here 350 hosts i am getting proper 200 response, other end up in 503 error.

Correct me if I am missing something here, Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It was basically typos in code, which were causing retry failure mechanism which were not working well.

```
s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
```

Missed to add ":" in "http"/"https". after adding ":" it worked well